# Python Program with sys.stdin gives error - Hadoop Streaming

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, stdin, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to learn hadoop streaming. I just wrote a three line python program to check whether everything is working fine but got stuck.

The code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print "Inside Loop"
```

The command I used to execute :

```
hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.5.1.jar  -file './test.py'  -mapper './test.py' -input ./sample.txt -output ./outfile
```

The error I am getting:

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:450)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)

15/01/25 17:09:55 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1418762215449_0069_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 127
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:450)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
```

I just want to check whether I can read the file stored in hdfs. I am just using a mapper to check this.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

This is a security issue: notice the message about UserGroupInformation

```
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:163)
```

It is not likely to be an easy fix for a beginner (I have several years of hadoop and do not particularly enjoy troubleshooting permissions/ACL issues..).  I recommend you work with someone who has set up clusters in the past.

Comment: This is probably a red herring. The error is most likely a failure of the mapper process, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34549515/396967).

Answer (score 1):

When I got this error it was due to CRLF line endings instead of LF.

You might check that.

I found the answer [here](http://blog.leituo.org/hadoop-streaming-error-when-try-to-map-reduce-with-python-on-macos-and-solution/).